# Is mutex() needed to safely access different elements of an array with 2 threads at once?

Tags: c++, arrays, multithreading

I am working weather data (lightning energy detected from a weather satellite). I have written a function that takes  satellite data (int) and inserts it into a multidimensional array after deciding which element it needs to be placed in.

The array is :
    int conus_grid[1180][520];

This has worked flawlessly, but it has taken too long to process and so I have written 2 functions that split the array so I can run 2 threads using std::thread. This is where the trouble happens... and I am doing my best to keep my examples to a minimum.

Here is my original function that accesses the array, and works fine. You can see my two loops to access the array: one being 0-1180 (x) and the other 0-520 (y) :

```
void writeCell(long double latitude, long double longitude, int energy)
{
    double lat = latitude;
    double lon = longitude;

for(int x=0;x<1180;x++)
{

    for(int y=0;y<520;y++)
    {


        // Check every cell for one that matches current lat and lon selection, then write into that cell.
        if(lon < conus_grid_west[x][y] && lon > conus_grid_east[x][y] && lat < conus_grid_north[x][y] && lat > conus_grid_south[x][y])
         {

            grid_used[x][y] = 1;
            conus_grid[x][y] = conus_grid[x][y] +  energy;  // this is where it accesses the array

        }       


    }
}


}
```

When I converted the code to take advantage of multithreading, I created the following functions (based on the one above, replacing it). The only difference is that they each access only one specific portion of the array. (Exactly one half each)

This first handles X... 0 to 590, and Y... 0 to 260 :

```
void writeCellT1(long double latitude, long double longitude, int energy)
{
    double lat = latitude;
    double lon = longitude;

for(int x=0;x<590;x++)
{

    for(int y=0;y<260;y++)
    {


        // Check every cell for one that matches current lat and lon selection, then write into that cell.
        if(lon < conus_grid_west[x][y] && lon > conus_grid_east[x][y] && lat < conus_grid_north[x][y] && lat > conus_grid_south[x][y])
         {

            grid_used[x][y] = 1;
            conus_grid[x][y] = conus_grid[x][y] +  energy;  // this is where it accesses the array

        }       


    }
}


}
```

The second handles the other half- X is 590-1180 and Y is 260-520 :

```
void writeCellT2(long double latitude, long double longitude, int energy)
{
    double lat = latitude;
    double lon = longitude;

for(int x=590;x<1180;x++)
{

    for(int y=260;y<520;y++)
    {


        // Check every cell for one that matches current lat and lon selection, then write into that cell.
        if(lon < conus_grid_west[x][y] && lon > conus_grid_east[x][y] && lat < conus_grid_north[x][y] && lat > conus_grid_south[x][y])
         {

            grid_used[x][y] = 1;
            conus_grid[x][y] = conus_grid[x][y] +  energy;  // this is where it accesses the array

        }       


    }
}


}
```

The program does not crash but there is data that is missing in the array once it completes - only part of the data is there. It's hard for me to track which elements it does not write, but it is clear that when I have *one* function to do this task, it works but when I have more than one thread accessing the array with 2 functions, it is not putting data in the array completely.

I figured it was worth a try to use mutex() like this :

```
        m.lock();
        grid_used[x][y] = 1;
        conus_grid[x][y] = conus_grid[x][y] +  energy; 
        m.unlock();
```

However, this does not work either as it gives the same result with failing to write data to the array. Any idea as to why this would be happening? This is only my 3rd day working with  so I hope it's something simple that I overlooked in tutorials.

Comment: What about `conus_grid_west` etc. What type are they?

Comment: If you can guarantee 100% that no threads will ever use the same element simultaneously, then no synchronization (with e.g. mutex) is needed. If you're even a fraction of a percent unsure, then add protection.

Comment: You split both X *and* Y ranges in half so between your two threads you only ever process half of the data.  What about data with X in 0 to 590 and Y in 260-520 for example?

Comment: To process a large data set, you may find threads one way to improve throughput.  But you should also consider using SIMD, and/or leveraging the GPU (using [OpenCL](https://www.khronos.org/opencl/), [Vulkan](https://www.khronos.org/vulkan/), or if suitable for your data [Halide](https://halide-lang.org/)).

Comment: If you have a regular grid, you could vastly speed this up by directly calculating the cell index.  It looks like are using negative longitude (degrees West), so take `x = (lon - east_edge) / cell_width`.  If your grid is not regular, but is based on a formula, you can still do this.  Perhaps project your lat/lon into meters for an area preserving projection?  If one had an arbitrary grid, then something like two binary searches in one dimension each, or a 2D tree like a quad-tree or KD-tree, could be used to get O(log (N*M)) time complexity instead of the O(N*M) you have now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is mutex() needed to safely access different elements of an array with 2 threads at once?

If you don't write to elements that may be written to or read by another thread at the same time, you don't need a mutex.

> The program does not crash but there is data that is missing in the array once it completes

As @G.M. implied, you should only split on one range (and it's `X` in this case), Otherwise you'll only handle half of the cells. One thread handles 1/4 and the other 1/4. You should split on X because you want each thread to handle data as closely placed as possible.

Note that data in 2D arrays is stored in row-major order in memory (which is why people usually use the notation `[Y][X]`) but it's fine to do as you do too. Splitting on `X` gives one thread half the memory rows and the other thread the other half.

---

An alternative could be to *not* do the thread management yourself. C++17 added [execution policies](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/execution) which lets you write loops where the body of the loop can be executed in different threads, usually picked from an internal thread pool. How many threads that will be used is then up to the C++ implementation and the hardware your program is executed on.

I've made an example where I've swapped X and Y and made some assumptions about the actual types you are using, for which I've created aliases.

```
#include <algorithm> // std::for_each
#include <array>
#include <execution> // std::execution::par
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>

// a class to keep everything together
struct conus {
    static constexpr size_t y_size = 520, x_size = 1180;

    // row aliases
    using conus_int_row_t = std::array<int, x_size>;
    using conus_bool_row_t = std::array<bool, x_size>;
    using conus_real_row_t = std::array<double, x_size>;

    // 2D array aliases
    using conus_grid_int_t = std::array<conus_int_row_t, y_size>;
    using conus_grid_bool_t = std::array<conus_bool_row_t, y_size>;
    using conus_grid_real_t = std::array<conus_real_row_t, y_size>;

    // a class to store the arrays
    struct conus_data_t {
        conus_grid_int_t conus_grid{};

        conus_grid_bool_t grid_used{};
        conus_grid_real_t conus_grid_west{}, conus_grid_east{},
                          conus_grid_north{}, conus_grid_south{};

        // an iterator to be able to loop over the row number in the arrays
        class iterator {
        public:
            using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;
            using value_type = unsigned;
            using difference_type = std::make_signed_t<value_type>;
            using pointer = value_type*;
            using reference = value_type&;

            iterator(unsigned y = 0) : current(y) {}
            iterator& operator++() {
                ++current;
                return *this;
            }
            bool operator!=(const iterator& rhs) const {
                return current != rhs.current;
            }
            unsigned operator*() { return current; }

        private:
            unsigned current;
        };

        // create iterators to use in loops
        iterator begin() { return {0}; }
        iterator end() { return {static_cast<unsigned>(conus_grid.size())}; }
    };

    // create arrays on the heap to save the stack
    std::unique_ptr<conus_data_t> data = std::make_unique<conus_data_t>();

    void writeCell(double lat, double lon, int energy) {
        // Below is the std::execution::parallel_policy in use.
        // A lambda, capturing its surrounding by reference, is called for each "y".

        std::for_each(std::execution::par, data->begin(), data->end(), [&](unsigned y) {
            // here we're most probably in a thread from the thread pool

            // references to the rows
            conus_int_row_t& row_grid = data->conus_grid[y];
            conus_bool_row_t& row_used = data->grid_used[y];
            conus_real_row_t& row_west = data->conus_grid_west[y];
            conus_real_row_t& row_east = data->conus_grid_east[y];
            conus_real_row_t& row_north = data->conus_grid_north[y];
            conus_real_row_t& row_south = data->conus_grid_south[y];

            for(unsigned x = 0; x < x_size; ++x) {
                // Check every cell for one that matches current lat
                // and lon selection, then write into that cell.

                if(lon < row_west[x] && lon > row_east[x] &&
                   lat < row_north[x] && lat > row_south[x])
                {
                    row_used[x] = true;
                    // this is where it accesses the array
                    row_grid[x] += energy;
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
```

If you use `g++` or `clang++` on Linux, you must link with `tbb` (add `-ltbb` when linking). Other compilers may have other library demands to be able to use execution policies. Visual Studio 2019 compiles and links it out-of-the-box if you select C++17 as your language.

I've often found that using `std::execution::par` is a quick and semi-easy way to speed things up, but you'll have to try it out yourself to see if it becomes faster on your target machine.